# Powering nichrome, possible to do it with AC?

Tags: transformer, efficiency

I am working on making a little nichrome-tipped pen for wax welding and planning to use a benchtop supply to provide the small amounts of DC needed to heat up the wire. Figuring out the right power and voltage requirements is pretty complicated.

Anyway, I was wondering hypothetically if a nichrome wire could be powered with AC electricity instead of DC? If so, I was thinking you could use a step up transformer to reduce the current of line voltage to power the nichrome more efficiently than by using a diode-based conversion to DC.

Comment: How long is the wire? What is the diameter?

Comment: To reduce the current through an essentially fixed resistance, you need a step-down transformer, not step-up. You can further control the power using an SCR or Triac.

Comment: @tut I think the OP has a constraint of some given temperature, so he'll be working at constant power, i.e. he'll be designing his resistance to dissipate a certain amount of power.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati ... Voltages near and above line voltage is nowhere near appropriate for a nichrome-tipped pen. Designing the resistance of the nichrome wire is backwards. He needs to supply the appropriate voltage (or current) to achieve the desired power based on the resistance of the wire. This will require a considerable reduction in RMS voltage which can be done with a step-down transformer and can be made adjustable using an SCR or Triac.

Comment: @Tyler Do you know what DC voltage from your benchtop supply you need to achieve the desire heat? You need to step-down your AC RMS voltage to that value (as the first line in Lorenzo's answer correctly indicates).

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly power any resistive element with AC, just use its RMS value as the equivalent value of DC.

The problem with step-up transformers is another: assuming you need a constant power to heat up your resistive element to the right temperature, lowering the current means to step up the voltage, which means more risks if you reach the order of tens of volts: 20Vrms may be deemed marginally safe (at least for the operator), 60Vrms are not (without proper insulation and earthing). Anyway always use a properly insulated transformer, i.e. one that has the secondary insulated from the primary (no autotransformers, i.e. inductive voltage dividers). And any exposed metal part should be earthed correctly to avoid hazards in case of failure (e.g. the mains live wire is shorted to the metal chassis/frame of the device).

Note that higher voltages may also cause other problems if the material you are going to melt is somewhat conductive and comes in contact with a live wire (i.e. the pen tip is not electrically insulated), since part of the current may flow in the material (I don't know much about the wax you'll be using). Anyway I'd go for lower voltages and higher currents.

BTW, if you are in the order of 10 watts probably you won't have efficiency problems on your mains lines. At 240V this means less than 50mA, which shouldn't cause too much loss on your lines.

Comment: Ok Lorenzo ... Sorry I have miss-interpreted what you were saying and I see now that you are indeed advocating low-voltage. I will delete my previous comments to your answer, but I will keep my comments on the main question as the OP was asking about using a step-up transformer which is dangerous and inappropriate.

Comment: @tut OK, don't worry. Misunderstandings happen on the global net :-). I'll delete my comments too, so as to clean things up. BTW, If you think some phrase in my answer was particularly ambiguous, please tell me. I'll be happy to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

In the model building comunity nichrome wire is used to cut foam to make wings and other flying model components. You can copy the design and yes, there are designs (adjustable) that use AC, but beware of designs running off the mains.